# get push stream in response send by server push with OkHttp

Tags: android, push, okhttp, http2

I am trying to test the push response from a server which support HTTP2 Server with an android app (Os=Android KitKat) .  The server push another ressources(pictures) after a http request for index.html.

I don't know how to access to push stream (picture). I have done capture on server and it send the push stream. But the client (Okhttp 2.1.0) always send a frame RST_STREAM and just return the index page content .
I just start use okhttp and would like to know how to acces push stream from Okhttpclient response ? I have read that that it exist API for handle push stream from HTTP2. is it available in Okhttp 2.1.0 or Okhttp 2.2.0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OkHttp doesn't implement pushed streams yet. When we do, it'll likely be to push into the cache only.

Comment: Thank Jesse, is it possible now with okhttp 2.2.0 to multiplexing http1 request in one connexion http2? I mean can i build one request with multiple url like pipelining apporach?